# Why do I get this database -(localdb)\\MSSQLLocalDB- exception on .netcore entity framework?

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I have an application in dotnet core and I can't access my local database -(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB- because the login fails for some reason.

Here is the exception:

```
Cannot open database "OdeToFood" requested by the login. The login failed.
Login failed for user 'DESKTOP-UBHMTGU\admin'.

{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "OdeToFood": "Server=(localdb)\\MSSQLLocalDB;Database=OdeToFood;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
  },

  "Greeting" :  "A configurable hello!"
}
```

Does anyone has any idea what is the problem?

Comment: Could you execute this command `sqllocaldb info mssqllocaldb ` in a cmd and display the result ?

Comment: I had the same problem once. I asked the asp team what was wrong. https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/7940

Comment: I solved it by adding Database.Migrate(); before I used the context.

Answer (score 2):

I solved it by adding Database.Migrate(); before I used the context.